# Hibernate: Transactions, Locks and DAO architecture in concurrent environment

Tags: java, hibernate, data-access-layer

Now I have basic DAO interface for `Entity` object (contextual data actually doesn't matter):

```java
public interface EntityDAO {

    CompletableFuture<Void> create(Entity entity);
    CompletableFuture<Optional<Entity>> get(String id);
    CompletableFuture<Void> update(Entity entity);
    CompletableFuture<Void> delete(Entity entity);

}
```

Imagine a situation when I needed to make thigs in this sequence:

1. Retrieve existing entity.
2. Do something operations with retrieved `Entity`.
3. Save changes.

Considering there is a possibility of simultaneous access to the `Entity` object while executing the business logic at step 2, I need to acquire a lock for the duration of its execution (`PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` I guess).

So, since locks bounded to transactions I need to keep transaction between `EntityDAO#get(String)` and `EntityDAO#update(Entity)` calls as far as I understood. This approach doesn't look correct and also makes it impossible to call `Entity#get(String)` and `EntityDAO#update(Entity)` independently of each other.

One of the solutions I came to is create a new one method (like below) that would allow you to get data with a lock, allow you to perform an action on the object, write changes and release the lock:

```java
CompletableFuture<Optional<Entity>> getAndSave(String id);
```

But I still don't think this approach is really the correct one.

So, **my question is**: How should I properly design a **database access layer** and **buisness logic layer** to achieve the above?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Can you please add some more details about "simultaneous access to the `Entity` object"? Do you mean by multithreading during a single input/request from outside, or will multiple parallel processed inputs/requests modify the same entity?

Comment: @cyberbrain Of course, actually I mean the second. I have several instances of the same app and the same entity data can be accessed by both another thread of a single instance and another instance of the app.